# How to call web page at the time of Passing Query Param in RestFul WebServices?

Tags: java, query-string

I am Passing one Query Parameter for updating the database column status value 0 to 1.
At the time of Updating that column.
I want to Display a Message to the User in the Same page.

```
 You Status was Updated Successfully.
```

else

```
You Status was not Updated.
```

How can I done both task at the time.

This messages i want to display in web page by using server code.

Any body can help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. You want to send a request that will update something on the database and once that transaction is completed (successfully or otherwise) return some message to display to the user concerning the state of the transaction? It would also be helpful if you could indicate which framework you are using on client side and on server side.

Comment: web client is abode flux and  server is resful webservices and jpa framework

Comment: Thanks for your Response.I have solved my issue

Comment: using  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) in my html code calling rest api.